# Airflow backfill command FERNET_KEY configuration missing

Tags: airflow

Having an issue doing a backfill. When I run this in the command-line

```
airflow backfill my_dag -s 2021-01-01 -e 2021-01-12
```

the dag is triggered and begins running. The first task (a simple python script with no external dependencies) completes but in the second task, I receive this error about fernet key. The dag is just calling a MsSqlOperator.

```
cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken
```

1. If I trigger the dag manually in the UI, all the steps succeed.
2. If I trigger one execution in the dag in the CLI, the dag succeeds.

   - `airflow dags trigger -e '2021-01-19T04:00:00' my_dag`
3. The fernet key is in the config file and we've already run resetdb and re-created the connections. Same issue exists, backfill command doesn't work but other methods do.
4. Also tried using the `--local` flag (not sure what this does) but it doesn't work either.

Any ideas how to troubleshoot?

Running [Airflow 1.10.14](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.14/) on-prem with LocalExecutor. Edit: Issue exists when using .15 too.

[Backfill Doc for Airflow 1.10.14](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.14/cli-ref.html#backfill)

Logs:

- Note, it says something about variable missing but that's misleading since it works if I manually run it from the UI. Key line is

  ```
   ERROR - Can't decrypt _val for key=xyz_users_overlap_import, FERNET_KEY configuration missing
  ```

Full log:

```
INFO - Job 4303: Subtask download_user_files
[2021-05-17 23:41:29,327] {{logging_mixin.py:120}} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: xyz_users_overlap_import.download_user_files 2021-01-22T15:10:00+00:00 [running]> on host da2m.mycorp.corp
[2021-05-17 23:41:29,360] {{variable.py:58}} ERROR - Can't decrypt _val for key=xyz_users_overlap_import, FERNET_KEY configuration missing
[2021-05-17 23:41:29,361] {{taskinstance.py:1150}} ERROR - 'Variable xyz_users_overlap_import does not exist'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 965, in _run_raw_task
    self.render_templates(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1424, in render_templates
    self.task.render_template_fields(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 719, in render_template_fields
    self._do_render_template_fields(self, self.template_fields, context, jinja_env, set())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 726, in _do_render_template_fields
    rendered_content = self.render_template(content, context, jinja_env, seen_oids)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 755, in render_template
    return jinja_env.from_string(content).render(**context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1090, in render
    self.environment.handle_exception()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 832, in handle_exception
    reraise(*rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 28, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "<template>", line 1, in top-level template code
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 471, in getattr
    return getattr(obj, attribute)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1335, in __getattr__
    self.var = Variable.get(item, deserialize_json=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/variable.py", line 117, in get
    raise KeyError('Variable {} does not exist'.format(key))
KeyError: 'Variable xyz_users_overlap_import does not exist'
```

Comment: Can you provide more logs from the backfill ? Also, have you tried to use `--reset_dagruns` ? Might be your previous dag_runs are blocking the backfill ?

Comment: @vdolez the dag does begin running and the first task succeeds (first task just runs some simple python with no dependency on variables or other connections/servers)

Comment: Might you also provide DAG code samples that are relevant please ? It seems a Variable is missing, are you using templated Jinja ? Calling the `Variable.get()` method ?

Comment: @vdolez - It's misleading. variable is not missing. Dag succeeds just fine when triggering the dag in the UI. Dag also succeeds when triggering via CLI like so
`airflow dags trigger -e '2021-01-19T04:00:00' my_dag`

Comment: Since the backfill is not executed the same way a DAG triggered with scheduler is, it might be relevant how you call the variable. Depending on execution context you might or not access the variable.

Comment: Btw, it also fails when not using a variable and the task has to look up the connection.. it's a fernet key issue.. it just doesn't make sense it works in every other scenario. I will try Alvaro's suggestion.

`reset_import_table = MsSqlOperator(task_id='reset_import_table',
                                            mssql_conn_id='ssis_etlstaging',
                                            sql='exec myproc')`

Comment: still, without the DAG conf it's hard to know what's happening, but i would advice against using `--local` since your local runner might not know your key, also take care of not posting sensitive information

Comment: So, will you provide code sample that calls the variable ? If you don't use Jinja, Variable.get is calling the Database. Without code, how can we help ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried by generating a new `FERNET_KEY` and set up as env variable (in this way you will overwrite the value from the `airflow.cfg` file):

`export AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY=your_fernet_key`

The code to generate a new one is:

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
fernet_key= Fernet.generate_key()
print(fernet_key.decode())
```

Do not forget to install before the package https://pypi.org/project/cryptography/ (`pip install cryptography`)

Comment: I can try it out although it seems strange that the dag succeeds when running it manually via the UI and via CLI `airflow dags trigger -e '2021-01-19T04:00:00' my_dag`

Comment: @Gabe You might need to do install this package should you use the `--local` runner